# Python class call a method from a class object

Tags: python, pandas, class, oop

How can I fix attribute error in this situation? I have a pandas dataframe where I make some data slicing and transformation and I want to plot the results of the persistence_model function like below.

Edit:
I want to customize a function with specific title of the plot, y and x axis and create a horizontal line on the same plot from the results of persitence_model function.

```
class ResidualErrors():
    def __init__(self, data: pd.Series):
        self.data = data
    def _persistence_forecast_model_nrows(self, test_rows):
        slicer = test_rows + 1
        errors = self.data[-slicer:].diff().dropna()
        return errors
    def _persistence_forecast_model_percrows(self, train_perc):
        n = len(self.data)
        ntrain = int(n * train_perc)
        errors = self.data[ntrain:].diff().dropna()
        return errors
    def persistence_model(self, test_rows=None, train_perc=None):
        if (not test_rows) and (not train_perc):
            raise TypeError(r"Please provide 'test_rows' or 'train_perc' arguments.")
        if test_rows and train_perc:
            raise TypeError(r"Please choose one argument either 'test_rows' or 'train_perc'.")
        if test_rows:
            return self._persistence_forecast_model_nrows(test_rows)
        else:
            return self._persistence_forecast_model_percrows(train_perc)

    @classmethod
    def plot_residuals(obj):
        obj.plot()
        plt.show()
```

Desired output

```
res = ResidualErrors(data).persistence_model(test_rows=10)

res.plot_residuals()

>> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'plot_residuals'
```

Comment: What are you trying to call `obj.plot()` on?  Do Pandas Series have a `.plot()` method?  I'm not sure.  Here your `persistence_model` method returns a `Series`, which you would then have to pass to `ResidualErrors.plot_residuals`.

Comment: `persistence_model` returns a Series. A series does not have a method `plot_residuals`.

Comment: I want to integrate the plotting inside the class so I can customize the title, and different matplotlib parameters.

Comment: @matt.aurelio ok, but I don't know why you expect a `@classmethod` to work that way. `obj` will be passed *the class*, i.e `ResidualErrors`. It's not clear why you expected `res.plot_residuals()` to work since `persistence_model` returns a `pandas.Series` object

Comment: ok - how can I make a function that takes the class object? should I make a new class? Can you give some guidance

Comment: You could change class method to `def plot_residuals(cls, ser): ser.plot();plt.show()`.  Then call with  `ResidualErrors.plot_residuals(res)`

Comment: @matt.aurelio it *does* take the class object. It is up to you to decide how you want your methods to work, how you expect this to work *isn't clear though*. Again, `res` is a `pd.Series` object, it's not going to have the `plot_residuals` method, because that method is defined on *your custom class*, not on the `pd.Series` class

Comment: What is not clear? From the pandas series, I want it to be able to have plot_residuals functions embedded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be more aware of what methods return. The first step creates a `ResidualErrors` object:

```
res = ResidualErrors(data)
```

The second step creates a `DataFrame` or `Series`:

```
obj = res.persistence_model(test_rows=10)
```

You can call `plot_residuals` on `res` but not on `obj`, as you are currently doing:

```
res.plot_residuals(obj)
```